# Como popular uma JTable usando um arquivo .txt?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, arquivo

Gostaria de saber como faço para popular um `JTable` usando um arquivo de texto pré existente.

[image: Imagem]

Tenho uma tabela de consulta e quero que o usuário ao colocar o número da conta, a mesma mostre os dados no `Jtable` e também como posso fazer a filtragem pelo número da agência ?

Os dados do meu arquivo de texto: http://pastebin.com/JwasUFKs

Aqui como eles estão representados respectivamente:

```
agencia;conta;data de lançamento; valor; operação.
```

Minha classe `ArquivoTextoProvider` que faz a leitura e gravação de dados:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArquivoTextoProvider {

    //Recebe como parãmetro o path do arquivo e o texto a ser gravado
    public static void gravar(String path,String texto){
        File arq = new File(path);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arq,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(texto+"\n");
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    //Recebe como parãmetro o path do arquivo a ser lido
    //Retorna um ArrayList com todas as linhas gravadas no arquivo
    public static ArrayList<String> carregarLinhas(String path){
        File arq = new File(path);
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(arq);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linha=null;
            ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lista.add(linha);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
            return lista;
        }catch (Exception ex){

            return null;
        }
    }

    //Recebe como parametro o simbolo separador e uma linha
    //e retorna um vetor de String preenchido com todos os dados separados pelo separado
    public static String[] lerDados(String separador, String linha){
        return linha.split(separador);
    }
}
```

Classe `telaConsulta`:

```
package view;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TelaConsulta extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TelaLogin
 */
public TelaConsulta() {
    initComponents();
    btConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //pesquisar a situaÃ§Ã£o
        }
    } );

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    edConta = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    edAgencia = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    edData1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    edData2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cbMes = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    btConsultar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    edSaldo = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Consulta");

    jLabel4.setText("Conta:");

    edConta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            edContaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Agencia");

    edAgencia.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            edAgenciaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setText("Data 1:");

    jLabel2.setText("Data 2:");

    edData2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            edData2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setText("Mes");

    cbMes.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" }));

    btConsultar.setText("Pesquisar");
    btConsultar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btConsultarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Data", "Valor", "Operacao"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    jLabel6.setText("Saldo: R$");

    edSaldo.setEditable(false);
    edSaldo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            edSaldoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(edSaldo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(btConsultar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(edConta))
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(edAgencia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(edData1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(edData2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(cbMes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addGap(114, 114, 114)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)))))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(edConta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(edAgencia, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(edData1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(edData2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cbMes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(btConsultar)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 253, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(edSaldo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

private void edContaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_edContaActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_edContaActionPerformed

private void edAgenciaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_edAgenciaActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_edAgenciaActionPerformed

private void edData2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_edData2ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_edData2ActionPerformed

private void btConsultarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btConsultarActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_btConsultarActionPerformed

private void edSaldoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_edSaldoActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}//GEN-LAST:event_edSaldoActionPerformed

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaConsulta.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaConsulta.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaConsulta.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaConsulta.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TelaConsulta().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JButton btConsultar;
private javax.swing.JComboBox cbMes;
private javax.swing.JTextField edAgencia;
private javax.swing.JTextField edConta;
private javax.swing.JTextField edData1;
private javax.swing.JTextField edData2;
private javax.swing.JTextField edSaldo;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primera coisa, evite gerador de código, principalmente este do NetBeans, é triste trabalhar com o código gerado por ele.

Se precisa de algum builder de interfaces para swing, considere usar o [`Window Builder`](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) no eclipse, o código gerado por ele é mais *decente*.

Vou tentar lhe ajudar, de uma forma simples e partindo do código gerado que você apresentou.

Para editar os dados de uma `JTable` é preciso atualizar os dados do [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) vinculado à `JTable`.

Veja este trecho gerado (`primeiro-trecho`):

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {{null, null, null}}, new String[] {"Data", "Valor", "Operacao"}) {
    Class[] types = new Class[] {java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class};
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[] {false, false, false};

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(final int columnIndex) {
        return types[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }

});
```

Veja que o `TableModel` da sua `JTable` é iniciado (`jTable1.setModel`) com uma `DefaultTableModel`, ainda sem dados (ou melhor, uma linha de dados nulos).

Para facilitar a manipulação dos dados, ao contrário de criar uma classe anônima como o gerador fez, que torna bem difícil de se trabalhar com os dados, crie uma classe que estenda de [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) e coloque este código gerado lá (você pode estender diretamente de [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) e implementar os métodos abstratos dele, eu prefiro, o código fica mais limpo e mais simples de ser customizado). Ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public MyTableModel(final Object[][] dados) {
        super(dados, new String[] {"Data", "Valor", "Operacao"});
    }

    // usaremos este método para atualizar os dados da JTable
    public void setDados(final Object[][] dados) {
        dataVector = super.convertToVector(dados);
    }

    private final Class[] types = new Class[] {java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class};
    private final boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[] {false, false, false};

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(final int columnIndex) {
        return types[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }

}
```

Agora, na `TelaConsulta` no lugar de termos aquele "`primeiro-trecho`" lá de cima, teremos algo assim:

```
final Object[][] dados = null;

final MyTableModel myTableModel = new MyTableModel(dados);

jTable1.setModel(myTableModel);
```

Para atualizar a tabela você deve alterar os `dados` da instância de `MyTableModel`, que é `myTableModel`, aquela que criamos anteriormente.

Como exemplo criei o método abaixo que lê um arquivo com as 5 linhas do arquivo que você forneceu e estou chamando ele no final de `initComponents` (`updateTable(jTable1);`). Ficou assim:

```
private void updateTable(final JTable jTable1) {
    final MyTableModel tableModel = (MyTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    final Object[][] dados = new Object[5][3];
    final List<String> lines = ArquivoTextoProvider.carregarLinhas("src/data.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        final String[] data = ArquivoTextoProvider.lerDados(";", lines.get(i));
        dados[i][0] = data[2];
        dados[i][1] = data[3];
        dados[i][2] = data[4];
    }

    tableModel.setDados(dados);
    // notifica o componente de que houve alteração, para que ele atualize considerando agora os novos dados
    jTable1.updateUI();
}
```

Depois disto, temos o seguinte resultado:

[image: Exemplo da JTable]

P.S.: todo o código foi editado em outro editor de texto, talvez o netbeans não deixe você alterar estas seções.

Comment: E como eu faço para fazer a filtragem pela agência ? Eu teria que fazer uma classe de controle só para esta funcionalidade ?

Comment: Cara mas como assim alterar os dados da instância de  MyTableModel ? Não entendi muito bem essa parte

Comment: E como eu chamo o método para o actionPerformed ?

Comment: @Jarwin **1)** Não entendi quando você diz fazer a filtragem pela agência. Você quer exibir tudo na tabela, depois filtrar? Se sim, deve implementar alguma coisa para filtro para isto, usando os dados do `TableModel` mesmo. **2)** A `JTable` tem uma instância de `MyTableModel` associada a ela. Para os dados serem atualizados a matriz de dados de `MyTableModel` deve ser alterada. **3)** Para chamar de um `actionPerformed` no seu exemplo, `jTable1` deve ser uma variável de instância, e não local.

Comment: A filtragem pela agência seria o usuário ao colocar o número da mesma, a JTable mostre os dados respectivos a esta agência.

Comment: @Jarwin Certo, daí tens que fazer algo para filtrar e reexibir na tabela mesmo.

Comment: Ok, valeu pela força aí cara.

Comment: Cara só uma duvida! Você usou o botão de pesquisar ou quando você inicia o projeto os dados já aparecem na JTable direto?

Comment: @Jarwin no exemplo não uso o botão, mas basta fazer como lhe disse num comentário anterior.